# How get List<~> fron View to Controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three related tables

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNdVR.jpg)

In the table "SelectedMaterial" need to enter the values in the column "CountMaterial" (initially there null)

[Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4acO.jpg)

For this in controller I have POST and GET methods

```
public ActionResult EditCountOfMaterial(int id)
    {
        var selectedmaterial = db.SelectedMaterials.Where(m => m.CardId == id).ToList();
        return View(selectedmaterial);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCountOfMaterial(List<SelectedMaterial> material)
    {
        //material = db.SelectedMaterials.Where(m => m.CardId == 3).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < material.Count; i++)
        {
            //material[i] = db.SelectedMaterials.Where(m => m.CardId == 3).First();
            db.Entry(material[i]).State = EntityState.Modified;               
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I also have a view

```
@model IEnumerable<AccountingPlusProject.Models.SelectedMaterial>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "EditCountOfMaterial";
}

<h2>EditCountOfMaterial</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @item.ReferenceMaterial.NameMaterial
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.CountMaterial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.CountMaterial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.CountMaterial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

But from the view comes null values. How to pass list from View with a value?

Comment: Your controls have to have a specific naming convention.   <input name="SelectedMaterial[0].Field">    <input name="SelectedMaterial[1].Field>   and so on and so on.

Comment: Could you give an example in the view with loop? Because the number of SelectedMaterial depends on the TechCard. What is my solution not correct?

Answer (score 0):

Something like Below.  The Posted back values have to be in array form.

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
     var count= 0;
     @item.ReferenceMaterial.NameMaterial
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.CountMaterial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
              @Html.EditorFor(model => item.CountMaterial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name="SelectedMaterial[" + count.ToString() + "].CountMaterial"} })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.CountMaterial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         </div>
      </div>
     count+=1;
     }

   }
```

Comment: Sorry for such a stupid question, but how in this case to use a button to send the data?

Comment: The button you have in the above example would work fine.    Any input button with type of 'Submit' will post the form data back.  You just have to name it correctly for MVC to bind it correctly to the expected Model in your controller

Comment: errors with the count, if use @using (Html.BeginForm())

Comment: if remove the @using (Html.BeginForm ()) then stops working <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />

Comment: replace count+=1; with @{count+=1;}

Comment: error in this line with "count" - @Html.EditorFor(model => item.CountMaterial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", name = "SelectedMaterial[" + count.ToString() + "].CountMaterial}" } })
and in this line  - { count += 1;}

Comment: Hold on...Let me edit in a project and Ill post the update above.

Comment: How can I send you my project?

Comment: The Above should work now.   Was missing a quote

Comment: After the fix still passes null in the POST:
 System.NullReferenceException:for (int i = 0; i < material.Count; i++)
 {

Comment: change your variable name in the controller from material to SelectedMaterial and see if that fixes it

Comment: need to change the input parameter?

Comment: I changed the name, but debug still in the beginning of the loop shows null

Comment: Can you run fiddler, etc and see what values are being posted back?

Comment: be sure your Class SelectedMaterial has an empty Constructor defined also

Comment: Class SelectedMaterial
namespace AccountingPlusProject.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class SelectedMaterial
    {
        public int CardId { get; set; }
        public int MaterialId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountMaterial { get; set; }
    
        public virtual ReferenceMaterial ReferenceMaterial { get; set; }
        public virtual TechnologicalCard TechnologicalCard { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: You need to add an empty constructor      Public SelectedMaterial(){}

Comment: I added a constructor, but the error is the same(